# Using this, or a similar script to it, how do I create a search script to search through the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
            success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);


        }
     });
```

**---**
Using that basic code, how do I now write a script for a search script similar to this one...

```
var text = ""; 

var times = 0; 

var textsearch = prompt("What would you like to search for?") 
for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length ; i++){ 
    if (text[i] == textsearch[0]){ 
        var okay = true;  
        for (var j = 1; j < textsearch.length; j++) { 
            if (textsearch[j] != text[i+j]) { 
                okay = false; 
                break; 
            }
        }
        if (okay == true){ 
            times += 1;    
        }
    }
}

console.log("Found " + textsearch + " " + times  + " times");
```

**----**
That searches through the object from http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp and searches for a team and the score?

Comment: What keys are the team and score in?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner so I don't really know what this means... AJAX??

Comment: Search keys i  mean for "team" and "score" , where so i search in object (Eg: for *htn* or *hts* ? )

Comment: Well my over all goal is to create something which searches for each team when I type each team into a search box. I'd like to pull the data from the object. basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/548Az/1/):

```
var textsearch = prompt("What would you like to search for?") 

if(textsearch)
{
    for (var key in text)
    { 
        if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htn') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('atn'))
        {
            if((text[key]['htn'].toLowerCase()).indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase()) != -1 || (text[key]['atn'].toLowerCase()).indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase())!=-1)
             times ++;
        }
     }
}

alert("Found " + textsearch + " " + times  + " times");
```

Comment: When I have this, how do I make it display the score of the game though.

Comment: like how do I make it say, "XYZ Team Won 3-1"

Comment: Can you ask a new question for this problem statement ? Thanks

Comment: Yes the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842339/how-do-i-rewrite-the-search-function-by-adding-a-for-loop-to-go-through-data-gam