# How do I rewrite the search function by adding a for loop to go through data.games and also add when I search that it says the score?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, search

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var textsearch = "XYZ"

    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
            success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);


if(textsearch)
{
    for (var key in data)
    { 
        if(data[key].hasOwnProperty('htn') && data[key].hasOwnProperty('atn'))
        {
            if((data[key]['htn'].toLowerCase()).indexOf(datasearch.toLowerCase()) != -1 || (data[key]['atn'].toLowerCase()).indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase())!=-1)
             times ++;
        }
     }
}

alert("Found " + textsearch + " " + times  + " times");
```

**----**
How do I rewrite the search function (from if (text search) down) in order to have it loop through data.games and also have it record the score as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/548Az/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/548Az/5/)

Just search for the word and fetch scores if there is a match and display

```
 for (var key in text)
    { 
        if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htn') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('hts'))
        {
            if(text[key]['htn'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase()) != -1)
            str= text[key]['htn']+ " vs "+ text[key]['atn']+ " score : "+ text[key]['hts']+"-"+text[key]['ats']+"\n";

            if( text[key]['atn'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase())!=-1)
            str += text[key]['atn'] + " vs "+ text[key]['htn']+ " score : "+ text[key]['ats']+"-"+text[key]['hts'];
        }
     }
    alert(str);
```

Comment: Very close, but the project is in a search box with a submit button so how can I write it so that when submit is hit (or enter) it alerts you of the score

Comment: So basically, how would I incorporate this fantastically written code with my project, 

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);

Comment: Haha thank you but for my project I am pulling it from the online API so would I need something like this?

$.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);

Comment: Check updated fiddle..its doing ajax call to the link you mentioned to fetch results.

Comment: Here is my project PLEASE take a look at it @Aditya https://mega.co.nz/#F!gJkB0Lab!9y3tb48sJ-mcdymu_4NIjA

Comment: Yes i see that u have the fiddle code there...should be working .Accept answer if it worked..Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if data.games is an array you could do

```
data.games.map(function(e){return e.score});
```

and you will get an array of scores.  If you want all of the scores added up you could do...

```
data.games
.map(function(e){return e.score})
.reduce(function(prev,current){return prev+current});
```

If you want the teams and the score

```
data.games.map(function(game){
    return{
        team1: game.team1Name,
        team2: game.team2Name,
        score: game.score
    }
});
```

That will give you an array of objects with the attributes of both team names and the score

Comment: Data.games is an array take a look here... http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/548Az/1/
but I want to clean up the search script I wrote before. Possibly a for loop to go through the array

Comment: And I want it over all to be when you type the team name or city it will display the score of that specific game